# Dealing with ambiguous names using Outlook.Recipients.Add("Alias")

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to tap into the company global Outlook address book from Excel using VBA.

It is set up to look at a selection of cells in a worksheet (assuming the selection contains userids) and loop through each userid (alias) and provide a message as to whether or not it is in the address book.

The company has differing lengths of aliases depending on job function (e.g. field associates are 14 characters, HQ associates are 6 characters).

There are cases where an alias from an HQ associate will match the first 6 characters of a field associate **(e.g. pbogar & pbogart.s04598)**. In these cases, the alias **(pbogar)** can not be resolved.

Is there a way to either display the same "check users" dialog box that Outlook would display if there are more than one user that share the same characters of an alias or to make sure that when it feeds through this code it only looks at aliases of a certain character length from the global address book?

```vb
Sub UserID_From_Email_Selection()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim Recip As Object
Dim Cell As Range

On Error GoTo err

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
For Each Cell In Selection
    If Cell.Value <> "" Then
        Set Recip = OutMail.Recipients.Add(Cell.Value)
        
        Recip.Resolve
        If Recip.resolved Then
            MsgBox (Recip & ": Resolved")
        Else
            MsgBox (Recip & ": Unresolved")
        End If

        Recip.Delete
        Set Recip = Nothing

    End If
Next Cell

On Error GoTo err

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

Exit Sub

err:
On Error Resume Next
     Set Recip = Nothing
     Set OutMail = Nothing
     Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much you can do using Outlook Object Model - it is either Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author - any language). In Redemption, you can use [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm)`.Recipients.ResolveAll`(**true**) to show the address book prompts (including an ambiguous recipient prompt) if necessary. You can also use [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm)`.Addressbook.ResolveName(name, **true**).`

To avoid problems like this, you might want to store the SMTP addresses (which are always unique) instead of the login aliases.